# Paramiko Segmentation Fault during Connect

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

I am trying to use paramiko to execute an ssh command remotely and get the results back. I run into an issue when trying to connect to the host. My code is as follows:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient
import paramiko
from socket import gethostbyaddr

root = '<path>/<to>/<key_file>'

client = SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
hostname = gethostbyaddr(instance.public_ip)[0]
client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=instance.user, key_filename=root)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("ls")
print(stdout.readlines())
client.close()
```

When I call `client.connect(...)` a segmentation fault occurs. I have tracked down the issue as far as `self.start()` on line `488` of `transport.py` with paramiko version 2.1.2 and python version 2.7.12.

Any help is appreciated!